# Can I safely use the HTML5 History API in a cross domain iframe?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, cross-domain, html5-history

I have a web application that users [HTML 5 History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) (pushState, etc).  I would like this application to be loadable in a cross-domain iframe (kinda like the FB or Twitter iframes).  A snipper of HTML (with the requisite iframe tags) could be inserted into any page, and this page would contain an iframed version of my app.  For example, if my web application is located at app.mywebapp.com, aRandomWebsite.com might have the following HTML structure

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://app.mywebapp.com/"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that [in the past](http://homakov.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-frames-can-mess-with-parents.html), cross-domain iframes were not entirely insulated from one another, and could mess with certain variables on eachother, like window.location.  My question is, if I execute the following code inside my iframed application, will the parent frame (which could be very hostile), be able to take a peek at it?

```
window.history({}, '', 'aSecureRoute/thisIdIsVerySensitive');
```

Comment: I guess it's sort of an open question about how vulnerable this can be to manipulation, but not at the moment, no.

Answer (score 0):

This should be safe as cross domain DOM access is protected by the [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

That said, there could possibly be quirks that makes it possible for `www.evil.com` to grab or [test URLs](http://homakov.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/pwning-your-privacy-in-all-browsers.html) in future versions of a popular browsers - it all depends on what vulnerabilities are discovered in future. As you cannot account for future browser bugs, I would recommend proceeding on the basis that this access *should* be protected. If any vulnerabilities are discovered you can direct your users to use a different browser until their current one is fixed.

Remember though that URLs should not be considered secure as they can be stored in the browser cache or history (or bookmarked), and also be logged by proxies (if not protected by HTTPS) or stored in server logs.

You should protect your secure URLs with something else too (e.g. a secure session cookie), so if the evil site grabs it it cannot then use it in future without the cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yeah, I'm aware that URLs aren't secure, but it won't be possible to "re-access" the URL without authentication.  What I'm worried about is that, if the path of the URL is exposed, the potentially hostile parent page will be able to parse it and deduce, for example, that user ID 1234 was looking at item ID 5678.  This is information I would rather keep private.